# How to fix : Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function?

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-script

I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function _themename\Lib\Classes\Enqueue::css(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 292 and at least 2 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\newtheme\lib\classes\Enqueue.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(292): _themename\Lib\Classes\Enqueue->css('') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\script-loader.php(2027): do_action('wp_enqueue_scri...') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(292): wp_enqueue_scripts('') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\general-template.php(3009): do_action('wp_head') #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\newtheme\header.php(8): wp_head() #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template.php(730): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template.php(676): load_template('C:\xampp\htdocs...', true, Array) #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\general-template.php(48): locate_template(Array, true, true, Array) #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\newtheme\index.php(19): get_header() #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template-loader.php(106): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php(17): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #16 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\newtheme\lib\classes\Enqueue.php on line 11
> There has been a critical error on this website.

there's a class file in my mytheme/lib/classes/Enqueue.php:

```
namespace _themename\Lib\Classes;

class Enqueue {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'css']);
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'js']);
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'admin_css']);
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'admin_js']);
    }
    public function css($handle, $path, $deps=[], $ver=false, $media='all') {
        wp_enqueue_style($handle, get_template_directory_uri() . $path, $deps, $ver, $media);
    }
    public function js($handle, $path, $deps=[], $ver=false, $media='all') {
        wp_enqueue_script($handle, get_template_directory_uri() . $path, $deps, $ver, $media);
    }
    public function admin_css($handle, $path, $deps=[], $var=false, $media='all') {
        wp_enqueue_style($handle, get_template_directory_uri() . $path, $deps, $ver, $media);
    }
    public function admin_js($handle, $path, $deps=[], $var=false, $media='all') {
        wp_enqueue_script($handle, get_template_directory_uri() . $path, $deps, $ver, $media);
    }
}
```

and another file mytheme/Lib/enqueue_assets.php:

```
<?php

namespace _themename\Lib;
require_once get_template_directory() . '/lib/classes/Enqueue.php';
use _themename\Lib\Classes\Enqueue;;
$enqueue = new Enqueue;


$enqueue->css('_themename-stylesheet', '/dist/assets/css/bundle.css', [], 1.0, 'all');
```

both of the files are included in function.php by require_once.
I am trying to learn object oriented php by creating a starter theme for myself.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error describes WordPress attempting to execute an action resulting in `Enqueue::css()` receiving too few arguments (it requires at least two).

In the constructor you are hooking `Enqueue::css()` to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. [When `wp_enqueue_scripts` is executed](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ad14ee34ebc6319cefb97a4c2dda6949e1d9bbe5/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L2071), it receives no additional arguments, so it calls `Enqueue::css()` with no arguments, triggering the error.

Long story short, all of your methods in the `Enqueue` class appear to be intended to enqueue scripts and stylesheets - there's no reason to attach them to `*_enqueue_scripts` action hooks. While functions hooked to those actions are an ideal place to enqueue scripts, hooking the functions which enqueue the scripts to them makes little sense - it is the equivalent of

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_script' );
```

The immediate solution is to remove all of the `add_action()` calls from your constructor; longer-term the `Enqueue` class's functionality will need to be re-assessed.

Comment: Thank you @bosco, I think i understand, what you are saying. I'm over doing it. Now my question is if enqueue css and js without the add_action() (like i delete the __constructor() ) would it be considered a good practice? For uploading it to wordpress repo?

Comment: PS: I am new user so I cannot upvote. Sorry.